# Xcode No Visible @interface for NSFetchedResults

Tags: xcode

I have a error with Xcode when writing a core data app. I am following [this tutorial](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ZoTAKAjEIFM&list=UU1Mnv8FyWlgnOgFy1m4CCLw) (from youtube).

At the 25:50 mark I am getting an error in Xcode.

My code is:

```
if (![[self fetchedResultsController]preformFetch:&error]) {
    NSLog(@"Error! %@", error);
    abort();
}
```

But I get an error:

> No visible @interface for 'NSFetchedResultsController' declares the
>   selector 'preformFetch'

What does this error mean, and how do I fix it?

Answer (score 0):

This can occur when you modify code date as you are coding.

In your simulator (or phone), delete the app, and delete any of the NSManagedObject Subclasses you have created.  Recreate your NSManagedObject Subclasses and run the app again.

Comment: ok after hours I found it and feel like a idiot.  I spelled performFetch preformFetch.   IDIOT stumpy!